# Auto expand textarea (AngularJs directive)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Need a bit of help with my directive for expanding a `<textarea>` element to show text as the user types into the field.

The idea is fairly simple. `<textarea>` elements look just like regular `<input>` elements until the logic determines there is not enough space for text and expands it by adding to the height.

I have a problem where elements that are hidden with `ng-show` or `ng-if` do not display correct height when `<textarea>` element is shown to the user based on some logic.

Is it possible to determine if the element has not been expanded and re run the directive on the element?

Directive

```
.directive('lwAutoExpand', function ($window) {
    var LinkFn = function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        element.css("overflow", "hidden");
        element.context.style.height = parseInt(element.css("line-height").replace("px", ""), 10) + parseInt(element.css("padding-top").replace("px", ""), 10) + parseInt(element.css("padding-bottom").replace("px", ""), 10) + "px";

        scope.$watch(function () { return ngModel.$modelValue; }, function (value) {
            if (element.context.scrollHeight > parseInt(element.context.style.height.replace("px", ""), 10)) {
                element.context.style.height = element.context.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });

        angular.element($window).on("resize", function () {
            if (element.context.scrollHeight > parseInt(element.context.style.height.replace("px", ""), 10)) {
                element.context.style.height = element.context.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: LinkFn,
    };
})
```

Html

```
<textarea placeholder="please type something into the field"
          ng-model="user_text"
          ng-if="display_element_based_on_another_elements_value"
          lw-auto-expand></textarea>
```

If someone has a better way of implementing the same directive please do not hesitate to show me how it's supposed to be done.

I am using AngularJs 1.5.8

Comment: What do you mean by "do not display correct height"? If the elements are hidden or not in the DOM at all (in case of ngif) they don't have a height. And how do these other DOM elements work together with your textarea?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I mean that when a hidden element is displayed to the user the directive does not run to correct elements height.

Comment: But why do these elements influence the height? According to your description the height of the `textarea` is only determined based in the length of its contents

Comment: Correct, but if the element is hidden at page load but becomes visible because of users interaction the height is not updated because the directive only executes at page load for all visible elements. Likewise, if an element was correctly displayed (height at page load) but was subsequently hidden (with ng-if) and displayed again the height is gone. To correctly display the element the directive would need to run again for that element.

Comment: Just to clarify something very important. If a hidden element (ng-if) becomes visible the height of the element is fixed to a single line even if there is more text than it can fit. If the user adds/removes a character or a space the directive detects a change in the model (I think) and updates the height.